# induction for preserving row structure of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, induction

Prove by induction for $n\geq 0$ that for a vector of the form $v=\begin{bmatrix}x& y& y& y\end{bmatrix}^T$, the vector $w=A^nv$ is of the same form, i.e. $w=\begin{bmatrix}d & z& z&z\end{bmatrix}^T$ where
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & a & c & 0 \\ b & 0 & 0 & a
\\ b & 0 & 0 & a \\ b & a& 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}.$$

The second and third rows are the same so it is a bit easier to do calculations, but the third row also has the same values so it gives a hint that the statement is true. The base case with $A=I$ is obvious, also with $A$. So I could suppose that the statement holds for $n$, and then $A^{n+1}v=A^nAv$. Since $Av$ gives a vector $w_1$ of the same form, by induction hypothesis $A^nw_1$ will also give a vector $w_2$ of the same form so that finishes the induction step. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this looks fine.